# 1.9: remove specific meta tag from header

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, meta-tags

Is it possible when looking at: 
Custom Design->Custom Layout Update XML

to completely remove a meta tag?

I'd like to remove the "robots" tag completely, as I will be adding in customized values for the pages using that template.

This is what I would use to CHANGE the value... but I'd like to remove it completely.

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots">
        <value>NOINDEX,FOLLOW</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible (and makes no sense). It is defined in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\head.phtml`

```
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>" />
```

You can copy this file to `app\design\frontend\YOUR\THEME\template\page\html\no-robot-head.phtml` and remove this line.

And add a layout update

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <path>page/html/no-robot-head.phtml</path>
    </action>
</reference>
```